# porting epoll to libevent

Tags: epoll, libevent, kqueue

I developed a server using epoll. It works fine under Linux. But I want to give macosx support using kqueue. I heard that libevent is a abstraction layer on top of these event based libraries(epoll, kqueue).

How can i port this code using epoll to libevent? example code: https://banu.com/blog/2/how-to-use-epoll-a-complete-example-in-c/epoll-example.c Is it possible (%100 compatible)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to alter parts of this code to use libevent instead of epoll. You will have to read libevent documentation in order to known exactly what you have to do, though.